# How do I connect to an AWS RDS with MySQL Workbench?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql, rds

I've read [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html) and several other sources but to no avail: I cannot connect to my MySQL instance from MySQL Workbench.

I can connect to my RDS instance through EC2, but I cannot dump from it because it is outdated:

```
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.1.71, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

And I receive this message:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)
```

My EC2 is running `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)`, so I cannot use the fix that is out there for the above issue.

So I want to connect to my RDS from Workbench. The mysql.exe that comes with MySQL Workbench:

```
mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.13, for Win32 (x86)
```

Which matches the version I am using for RDS, which is `mysql(5.6.13)`. Sadly, MySQL Workbench gives me the following:

```
Cannot Connect to Database Server
Your connection attempt failed for user '' from your host to server at ...: Can't connect to MySQL server on '' (10060).
```

So the good news is that I am now able to connect to my RDS using my EC2 instance as an SSH pipe. I can post this in an answer and accept it if my question is reopened.

Bad news is that I might still need to publicly access my RDS sometime in the future. I found [this blog post](http://www.caseylabs.com/connecting-to-an-rds-endpoint-in-vpc-externally-from-the-outside-world), but it seems to be outdated and did not help. Maybe I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I posted this question here specifically because it was on-topic. Where else would I post it? Stack Overflow? Super User? I would appreciate some feedback as to where I can post this question on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed MySQL Workbench on your local PC, you might need to check out the Security group of your RDS instance and make sure that it's allowing connection from your network. Under the 'Security Groups' tab in RDS page, look for the desired Security group and click the magnifier-like icon beside the name to show the details.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention my current security group. I have a custom protocol ALL under inbound and outbound rules where my personal IP is. I'm also allowing inbound MySQL connections (3306) specifically from my network.